# CSS style is not getting updated in react

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, browser, browser-cache

I had a FileUpload.module.css file where I had this line of code.

```
input { display: none; }
```

Now I am trying to remove this style. But somehow this style is still in effect. I have even deleted the FileUpload.module.css file from my repo. I cleared the browser cache, and npm cache (it is a react project). I even deleted node_modules and re-downloaded it using `npm install`. But this style won't go away. When I inspect and select the input tag, `input { display: none; }` is still shown in the styles tab. And it shows that this style is from FileUpload.module.css. How is this possible? I am using Chrome. I even tried incognito but not working either.

Comment: Did you rebuild your React project?

Comment: I have been running the project using npm start in dev environment. I haven't built it.